# Post install errors Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, failed-installation

[Error screenshot]

[image]

How do I fix this?

I have the option to abort, retry or ignore

What should I do?

I had anaconda before and everything was ok but I uninstalled it due to everything being everywhere.

If you could give me a helping hand

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is abort the operation, and then completely reinstall the application, but maybe you need to update your version of python.

Comment: Well its the latest python. Is it anything to do with PATHs? Python is recognised...3.7.0. Its just I don't have spyder etc. I could pip install but...usually I would have it in my start menu

Comment: According to the conda documentation it may not support python 3.7
https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html maybe that is the problem with your anaconda install.

Comment: Reinstalled windows. Worked after. When I uninstalled anaconda I messed about with some files. But all good. Thanks for your help

Comment: Isn't the point of anaconda to install python?  Why would you already have python installed?